# Get an site column text field that is only displayable in editmode in published page

Tags: web-part, javascript, page-layout

```
        <PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel ID="EditModePanel1" runat="server" CssClass="edit-mode-panel title-edit">

         <div id="NBSBranchAccountName">
            <SharePointWebControls:TextField ID="BranchAccountName" runat="server" FieldName="NBSBranchAccountName"/>
        </div>



        </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

I have this text field which is only displayable in editmode. How can I get the value of the form in publish mode in javascript as the normal `jQuery.trim(jQuery('#NBSBranchAccountName').val());` won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrive list item with javascript object model and get the field value from list item:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx